# How to reverse this SCSS animation?

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is a code which actually creates a recording button. when you click the button the circle inside turns to a square. If you click again on the square it turns to circle again this time without any animation.

As I know next to nothing about SCSS I need some help to modify this code.

How can I **Animate** the square shape back to the circle?

First here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/pmXbNz).

And here is the code:

HTML

```
.container
  input(type="checkbox" id="btn")
  label(for="btn")
  .time
    .h_m
    .s_ms
```

SCSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

$bg: #000;
$red: rgb(232, 4, 21);
$white: #fff;
$grey: rgb(162, 162, 162);
$cont-size: 170px;
$outer-size: $cont-size - 40;
$inner-size: $outer-size - 30;
$border-size: 6px;
$sec: 1s;
$bezier: cubic-bezier(.4, -.9, .9, 1);

@mixin animation($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {@content;}
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {@content;}
    @-o-keyframes #{$name} {@content;}
    @keyframes #{$name} {@content;}
}

@mixin animation-use($name, $time, $easing) {
    -webkit-animation: $name $time infinite $easing;
    -moz-animation: $name $time infinite $easing;
    -o-animation: $name $time infinite $easing;
    animation: $name $time infinite $easing;
}

@mixin animate($val, $colon) {
    @include animation(to_ + $val) {
        @for $i from 1 to $val {
            #{100/$val*$i}% {
                @if ($i < 10) {
                    content: $colon + '0' + $i;
                } @else {
                    content: $colon + '' + $i;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}

@mixin pseudo($content) {
    position: relative;
    content: $content;
}

@mixin center($val) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: $val;
    height: $val;
    margin: -$val/2 0 -$val/2;
}

@mixin delay($time) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: $time;
    animation-delay: $time;
}

@mixin once() {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@include animate(24, '');
@include animate(60, ':');
@include animate(100, ':');

@include animation(time) {
    to {
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@include animation(stop) {
    70% {
        border-radius: 6px;
        @include center($inner-size - 40);
    } 100% {
        border-radius: 6px;
        @include center($inner-size - 36);
    }
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: $bg;

    .container {
        @include center($cont-size);

        #btn {
            display: none;

            & + label:before {
                @include center($outer-size);
                content: '';
                -webkit-transform: translate(-$border-size, -$border-size);
                -ms-transform: translate(-$border-size, -$border-size);
                transform: translate(-$border-size, -$border-size);
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: $border-size solid $white;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            & + label:after {
                @include center($inner-size);
                content: '';
                border-radius: $inner-size/2;
                background: $red;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            &:checked {
                & + label:after {
                    @include animation-use(stop, 0.5*$sec, $bezier);
                    @include once();
                }

                & ~ .time {
                    @include animation-use(time, 0.3*$sec, linear);
                    @include once();
                    animation-delay: 0.3*$sec;
                }

                & ~ .time .h_m:after {
                    @include animation-use(to_24, 86400*$sec, linear);
                    @include delay(1800*$sec);
                }

                & ~ .time .h_m:before {
                    @include animation-use(to_60, 3600*$sec, linear);
                    @include delay(30*$sec);
                }

                & ~ .time .s_ms:before {
                    @include animation-use(to_60, 60*$sec, linear);
                    @include delay(.5*$sec);
                }

                & ~ .time .s_ms:after {
                    @include animation-use(to_100, $sec, linear);
                }
            }
        }

        .time {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 110%;
            opacity: 0;

            & > * {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 50%;
                margin: -2px;
                color: $grey;
                font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; 
                font-size: 1.3em;
            }

            .h_m:after {
                float: right;
                @include pseudo('00');
            }

            .h_m:before {
                float: right;
                @include pseudo(':00');
            }

            .s_ms:before {
                float: left;
                @include pseudo(':00');
            }

            .s_ms:after {
                float: left;
                @include pseudo(':00');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is too tough to study, wait while

Comment: @SaraRee you can `animation-direction: reverse;` to make your animation backward (https://cssreference.io/property/animation-direction/) on checkbox:unchecked. also you probably need to add abit js (to handle clicking the checkbox), because i think there is no different between initial state and after user uncheck the checkbox in css. you can toogle between `unchecked` and `checked` class on checkbox click.

Comment: You should probably make a separate question for the keyframe thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SCSS is just a faster way of writing CSS. You can get the "processed" CSS in Codepen by clicking the down arrow in the CSS pane and selecting view compiled CSS However, the SCSS, in this case, is mostly for the timecode display, not the button animation.

---

**Here's a simplified version (using plain CSS) of what's being done in that example.**

Basically, there's a checkbox and if it's checked the circle becomes a square. If not it goes back to the first state which is a circle.

This is using `:checked` to find out if the input is "selected" and the setting the `adjacent sibling` in this case the span to have a different `border-radius`. `CSS Transition` is used to animate between the two states.

```css
label {
  display:block;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span {
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.4, -.9, .9, 1);
}

input {
  display:none;
}

input + span {
  /* normal is a circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + span {
  /* when the input is selected change to square */
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" />
   <span></span>
</label>
```

---

## *Edit* with keyframe animation.

I forked and modified the [codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/qGzqOW) to see if I could get this to work easily with the checkbox. But as expected the `state` isn't maintained with the checkbox and it just jumps.

---

And here's another fork of the [codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/dEBONG) using the transition technique I mentioned above that does work consistently.

Comment: @BryceHowitson but the question uses "keyframe animation", isn't it diferent to reverse "keyframe animation" in comparison to transition?

Comment: The keyframe animation is only for the timecode display in the example. Yes it's different to reverse a keyframe animation, but the OP asked how to make the circle -> square -> circle interaction. This is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Wow... Great and still simple solution... Thanks for the answer... But I'm curious to know how to modify the provided code (using SCSS) in order to reverse those keyframe animations...

Comment: @SaraRee I just noticed that the example snaps back to a circle (no animation). `keyframe animation` doesn't manage "state". You would need two animations `toCircle` and `toSquare` for example and something to manage the state. It might be able to be done with the checkbox but I'd have to play a bit. Also, you don't need to use SCSS for this. The example is using it to make managing the counter easier but it really just adds bloat. Also, SCSS compiles to CSS so if you don't need what SCSS does you can ignore it.